# Changing biblatex's sorting within the document

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber, sorting, options

I am using multiple refsections in my document and I need to sort the respective bibliographies differently. E.g., let's say I want one refsection to be as

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=ymdnt,style=phys]{biblatex}%
```

and another refsection as

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=none,style=phys]{biblatex}%
```

I can set this individually in the preamble and one of the two sections works as expected, and the other one is (obviously) not as wanted.
Currentl I stitch the PDF together from two runs of either sorting and using the appropriate pages from either PDF to create a new one.

The bib latex manual seems to indicate that the sorting option can only be changed by the package option. Nevertheless, I was wondering if it was somehow possible to bypass this and to change(fudge?) the sorting some point in the manuscript?

I am using LuaLaTeX and biber (most current versions from MacTeX, e.g., biblatex 3.0).
All hints are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a refcontext:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\cite{shore}\cite{aksin}

\printbibliography


\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nty]
\cite{shore}\cite{aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}

\end{document}
```

[image]